# Minimizing $ |t|^2 + a(|t + u| - |u|) $ over $ t \in \mathbb{C} $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers, absolute-value

I'm not so experienced with *Complex Analysis* and I somewhere stumbled upon the following function $ f: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ that I need to minimize with respect to the *Complex* variable $ t $ ($ t \neq 0 $):

$$ f(t, u) = |t|^2 + a(|t + u| - |u|), $$

where $ u $ is also *Complex* and $ a $ is a known *Real* constant (I can also assume $ a \geq 0 $). I wonder if I can find an explicit solution (even considering cases) for $ \hat{t} $ the minimizer, and if so I would appreciate if one can help me how to proceed?

Comment: Do you know if $a$ is positive or negative?

Comment: @DOUGLASBRUNSON it is not given, but I think based on the problem it can be assumed to be positive if it helps.

Comment: @Sina90 Hint: minimize the real function $\,|t|^2 + a \big||t|-|u|\big|\,$, then find the complex $\,t\,$'s such that $\,|t+u|=\big||t|-|u|\big|\,$

Comment: @dxiv I edited the question a bit to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @Sina90 IMHO there was nothing wrong with the original $f(t)$ notation, since $t$ is the free variable here, and $u$ is just a constant for minimization purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the hint in my comment, here is a way to solve it without calculus, using just basic algebra and the triangle inequality for complex numbers.

- For constant $u$ the last term in $f(t) = |t|^2 + a|t + u| - a|u|$ is a constant, so minimizing $f(t)$ is equivalent to minimizing $g(t) = |t|^2 + a|t + u|\,$.
- $|t+u| \ge \big||t| - |u|\big|$ by the triangle inequality, with equality iff $t = \lambda u$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb R^-$.
- Then $\,g(t) = |t|^2 + a|t + u| \;\ge\; |t|^2+a\big||t|-|u|\big|\,$ when $\,a \ge 0\,$.
- With $|t|=r \in  \mathbb R^+$ the real function $h(r)=r^2 + a\big|r-|u|\big|$ has a minimum at either $\,r_0=|u|\,$ or $\,r_0=a/2\,$ depending on $\,a,u\,$.
- Piecing it all together, $\,f(t)+a|u|=g(t)\ge h\left(|t|\right) \ge h(r_0)\,$ with equality when $\,|t|=r_0\,$ *and* the triangle inequality becomes an equality, so $\,t_0=-\frac{u}{|u|}r_0\,$.

Comment: Nice approach! but I didn't fully understand why $ t = \lambda u $. Also doesn't $ r_0 = a/2 $ violate $ t = \lambda u $? I know that when $ t $ and $ u $ are real $ r = a/2 $ is the minimizer but I'm curious how it fits into yours sol'n? Thanks.

Comment: Further how could you conclude that $ t_0 = -\frac{u}{|u|}r_0 $? Is this derived from the achievement of the lower bound? but how? Thanks very much again.

Comment: @Sina90 I edited the last point to hopefully make everything more clear. The triangle inequality works the same as in geometry between three points $BC \ge \big|AB-AC\big|$ with equality iff $A,B,C$ are collinear and $B$ is between $A$ and $C$. Translated in complex numbers, this means $t$ is a negative real multiple of $u$.

Comment: It makes perfect sense now, thank you very much! I'll keep the post open for another day for other potential comments or answers, and then will accept this answer as the best.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid complex variables and transfer all of them to the Euclidean space. Let us denote the real part and the imaginary part of a complex number $ u $ as $ R(u) $ and $ I(u) $, so that $ u = R(u) + i I(u) $. Using this notation, you have

$$ f(t, u) = (R(t))^2 + (I(t))^2 + a \left( \sqrt{(R(t) + R(u))^2 + (I(t) + I(u))^2} - \sqrt{(R(u))^2 + (I(u))^2} \right) . $$

Minimizing $ f(t, u) $ with respect to $ t $ is same as minimizing

$$ g(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 + a \left( \sqrt{(x + R(u))^2 + (y + I(u))^2} - \sqrt{(R(u))^2 + (I(u))^2} \right) $$

with respect to real valued variables $ x $ and $ y $ and then taking $ \hat{t} = \hat{x} + i \hat{y} $, where $ (\hat{x} , \hat{y}) $ minimizes $ g(x, y) $. Since $ g(x, y) $ is a differentiable function of $ x, y $, you can use derivative of $ g(x, y) $ with respect to $ x, y $ to find the minimizers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This approach is what I tried at the beginning and because the calculations had become tedious I couldn't wrap it up with this method. In particular I found a sol'n set that I wasn't sure which one was the correct minimizer, and computing the Hessian or substitution was making it even more messy.

Comment: I agree that the approach using differentiation is a bit messy. dxiv's approach seems better.

Answer (score 2):

This is just expanding on @dxiv: idea. Say we have a normed space $E$, $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ increasing functions on $[0, \infty)$, $x_1$, $x_2$ points in $E$. Consider the function
$$E\ni x \mapsto f(x) \colon= \phi_1 (d(x, x_1)) + \phi_2 (d(x, x_2))$$
If $f$ has a point of minimum, then it has a point of minimum on the segment $[x_1, x_2]$.

Proof: It is enough to show that for every $x\in E$ there exists $x'\in [x_1, x_2]$ with $f(x')\le f(x)$. We distinguish two cases:

1. $d(x_1, x) > d(x_1, x_2)$. Then we have $f(x_2)\le f(x)$.
2. $d(x_1, x)\le d(x_1, x_2)$. Consider $x'$ the (unique) point on the segment $[x_1, x_2]$ such that $ d(x_1, x') = d(x_1, x)$. From the triangle inequality we get $d(x', x_2) \le d(x, x_2)$. We conclude $f(x')\le f(x)$.